Optimizing a for loop with lookup-table using ARM Neon instructions
This is one of my first code in Neon, I want to know if you have any comments or suggestions to improve the code to run faster, that's why I translate the code to that low level.
I posted the code on Code Review site but I didn't get any reply and my post was the only one with Neon tag so I thought to post it here.
Here is a working code. This code applies a lookup table for an image. My goal is to make the code run faster on ARM cortex A53 CPU.
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> // For std::iota
#include <array> // Structure to hold cached parameters

#ifdef __ARM_NEON
#include <arm_neon.h>
#else
#error "ARM Compiler required."
#endif

struct Cache {
    std::array<uchar, 256> lut_b;
    std::array<uchar, 256> lut_g;
    std::array<uchar, 256> lut_r;
};

// Function to compute simple example data and lookup tables
void compute_data(const cv::Mat& image, Cache& cache) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        cache.lut_b[i] = static_cast<uchar>(i);
        cache.lut_g[i] = static_cast<uchar>(i);
        cache.lut_r[i] = static_cast<uchar>(i);
    }
}

// Function to apply lookup table. vy[i] = vtable[vx[i]]
static inline uint8x16_t lookup_neon(const uint8x16x4_t vtable[4], uint8x16_t vx) {
    const uint8x16_t voffset = vmovq_n_u8(64);
    uint8x16_t vy = vqtbl4q_u8(vtable[0], vx);
    vx = vsubq_u8(vx, voffset);
    vy = vqtbx4q_u8(vy, vtable[1], vx);
    vx = vsubq_u8(vx, voffset);
    vy = vqtbx4q_u8(vy, vtable[2], vx);
    vx = vsubq_u8(vx, voffset);
    vy = vqtbx4q_u8(vy, vtable[3], vx);
    return vy;
}

void hist(cv::Mat& image, Cache& cache, bool use_cache) {
    if (!use_cache) {
        compute_data(image, cache);
    }
    // Load cache in registers. (4x4 128-bit registers)
    const uint8x16x4_t vtable_b[4] = {
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_b.data() + 16 * 4 * 0),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_b.data() + 16 * 4 * 1),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_b.data() + 16 * 4 * 2),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_b.data() + 16 * 4 * 3)
    };
    const uint8x16x4_t vtable_g[4] = {
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_g.data() + 16 * 4 * 0),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_g.data() + 16 * 4 * 1),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_g.data() + 16 * 4 * 2),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_g.data() + 16 * 4 * 3)
    };
    const uint8x16x4_t vtable_r[4] = {
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_r.data() + 16 * 4 * 0),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_r.data() + 16 * 4 * 1),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_r.data() + 16 * 4 * 2),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_r.data() + 16 * 4 * 3)
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i) {
        uint8_t* row_ptr = image.ptr(i);
        int j = 0;
        // Apply transformation on elements multiple of 16.
        for (; (j + 16) <= image.cols; j += 16) {
            // Load and deinterleave the elements.
            uint8x16x3_t vec = vld3q_u8(row_ptr);
            vec.val[0] = lookup_neon(vtable_b, vec.val[0]);
            vec.val[1] = lookup_neon(vtable_g, vec.val[1]);
            vec.val[2] = lookup_neon(vtable_r, vec.val[2]);
            vst3q_u8(row_ptr, vec);
            // Interleave and stores the elements.
            row_ptr += 3 * 16;
        }
        // Apply transformation on leftover elements.
        for (; j < image.cols; ++j) {
            row_ptr[0] = cache.lut_b[row_ptr[0]];
            row_ptr[1] = cache.lut_g[row_ptr[1]];
            row_ptr[2] = cache.lut_r[row_ptr[2]];
            row_ptr += 3;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Open the video file
    cv::VideoCapture cap("video.mp4");
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening video file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Get the frame rate of the video
    double fps = cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int delay = static_cast<int>(1000 / fps);

    // Create a window to display the video
    cv::namedWindow("Processed Video", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);

    cv::Mat frame;
    Cache cache;
    int frame_count = 0;
    int recompute_interval = 5; // Recompute every 5 frames

    while (true) {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) {
            break;
        }

        // Determine whether to use the cache or recompute the data
        bool use_cache = (frame_count % recompute_interval != 0);

        // Process the frame using cached or recomputed parameters
        hist(frame, cache, use_cache);

        // Display the processed frame
        cv::imshow("Processed Video", frame);

        // Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
        if (cv::waitKey(delay) == 'q') {
            break;
        }

        frame_count++;
    }

    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}


What this code suppose to do? IMO instead playing with neon you should  investigate if this problem can be solve by OpenCV API (which you already using). OpenCV can use hardware which will be faster then CPU.

For better performance, you should change your cache structure:  struct Row { uchar lut_b; uchar lut_g; uchar lut_r;}; std::vector<Row> Cache;  This places the rgb components next to another (likely on the same Cache line).  In your present implementation, the processor may have to reload the data cache to get the other array elements.

@MarekR I have an image as input and I process it using the LUT. In compute data function I do have more processing than what I showed. I didn't show more details because this function runs only once in while.
What hardware can be used by OpenCV instead of a CPU? I tried cv::lut but it processes each channel separately so I need to separate the channels, run cv::lut three times and then merge the image again each new frame which makes the whole code slower.

@ThomasMatthews Yes I think you're right. Then I should do something like vld1q_u8_x4(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&cache[0]), correct?

@Ja_cpp OpenCV is optimize to use vector operation on available hardware, GPU or CPU. For example when I was converting image from YUV422 to RGB I used OpenGL and code was faster at least two orders of magnitude. Check out if this can help solve your problem: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab55b8d062b7f5587720ede032d34156f

might be a candidate for the [codereview.se] SE -- OpenCV uses OpenCL (cee-ell, not gee-ell) for a lot of things, if you allow it. that is done by using UMat to wrap a Mat. That's a data type that allows data to be used on a GPU. lots of basic functions in OpenCV come with OpenCL kernels to operate on UMat types. OpenCL can be targeted to various CPUs, including ARM (probably utilizing its neon vector instructions).

@ChristophRackwitz I didn't try cv::LUT on ARM yet but on intel computer it wasn't faster than manually applying lookup table and using cv::parallel_for_. I'll try on ARM and see if I get better results but the fact that I need to separate the channels and then merging them take some time, that why I'm trying to avoid that and implement something myself that might bit faster.

I totally see that. all this abstraction helps get you mostly to peak performance, for most use cases, but for the rest you will need to DIY.

Your LUT is far exceeding the size of the register file - i.e. you have 16 or 32 quad registers depending if your code is 32-bit or 64-bit.  You're trying to load 48 registers of lookup table ...

@solidpixel that's correct. I'm a very beginner into that field and I'm open to any remarks or suggestions

EDIT: TL;DR -- scroll down for the very last section

As pointed in the comments, 3 distinct lookup tables require 48 registers, which is absolutely too much; the generated code will spill a lot.
The first thing to consider is to think if the LUT is computing an elementary function, which could be approximated with piecewise linear, quadratic or maybe up to cubic functions, since in many older platforms at least the vtbl and vtbx instructions do not instruction-level parallelise and require about ~12 cycles for a 64-element lookup. Even promoting the uint8_t -> float for square root and back to uint8_t is likely a feasible solution for inverse gamma correction.
If a LUT is unavoidable, I would probably split the work into 4 passes, loading just one quarter of a table into registers in any given moment.
    uint8x16x4_t table_r = vld1q_u8_x4(table_r_ptr);
    uint8x16x4_t table_g = vld1q_u8_x4(table_g_ptr);
    uint8x16x4_t table_b = vld1q_u8_x4(table_b_ptr);
    table_r_ptr+=64;
    table_g_ptr+=64;
    table_b_ptr+=64;
    do {
       uint8x16x3_t data = vld3q_u8(source); source += 48;
       data.val[0] = vqtbl4q_u8(table_r, data.val[0]);
       data.val[1] = vqtbl4q_u8(table_g, data.val[1]);
       data.val[2] = vqtbl4q_u8(table_b, data.val[2]);
       vst3q_u8(destination, data); destination += 48;
    } while (--full_blocks);
    ...
    // then the 3 other passes
    for (int pass = 64; pass <= 192; pass += 64) {
      // load more tables
      table_r = vld1q_u8_x4(table_r_ptr); table_r_ptr+=64;
      table_g = vld1q_u8_x4(table_g_ptr); table_g_ptr+=64;
      table_b = vld1q_u8_x4(table_b_ptr); table_b_ptr+=64;
      // need to rewind the pointers
      source -= pixels * 3;
      destination -= pixels * 3;
      int full_blocks = pixels / 16;
      do {
         uint8x16x3_t data = vld3q_u8(source); source += 48;
         uint8x16x3_t datad = vld3q_u8(destination);

         data.val[0] = vsubq_u8(data.val[0], vdupq_n_u8(pass));
         data.val[1] = vsubq_u8(data.val[1], vdupq_n_u8(pass));
         data.val[2] = vsubq_u8(data.val[2], vdupq_n_u8(pass));

         datad.val[0] = vqtbx4q_u8(datad.val[0], table_r, data.val[0]);
         datad.val[1] = vqtbx4q_u8(datad.val[0], table_g, data.val[1]);
         datad.val[2] = vqtbx4q_u8(datad.val[0], table_b, data.val[2]);
         vst3q_u8(destination, data); destination += 48;
       } while (--full_blocks);
    }

Rethinking -- while that approach is straightforward, it does require writing 4 times the amount of the data and reading it 7 times.
One might instead consider keeping at least some of the tables in register and use some fixed registers to reload the changing portion of the look up tables;
    uint8x16x4_t r0,g0,b0, r1,g1,b1;
    loadFirstHalfOfTables(r0,g0,b0, r1,g1,b1);
    {
       uint8x16x3_t data = vld3q_u8(source += 48);
       uint8x16_t tmp = vqtbl4q_u8(r0, data.val[0]);
       // so far we have used 4 registers and have 4 left
       // but we need 5 registers in fact. Let's reuse one
       // register from the tables
       r0.val[0] = vdupq_n_u8(64);

       data.val[0] -= r0.val[0];
       tmp = vqtbx4q_u8(tmp, r1, data.val[0]);
       data.val[0] -= r0.val[0];
       uint8x16x4_t r2 = vld4q_u8_x4(table_r + 128);
       tmp = vqtbx4q_u8(tmp, r2, data.val[0]);
       data.val[0] -= r0.val[0];
       r2 = vld4q_u8_x4(table_r + 192);
       data.val[0] = vqtbx4q_u8(tmp, r2, data.val[0]);
       // do the same for G,B channels
       

       r0.val[0] = vld1q_u8(r_table); // restore spilled register
       vst3q_u8(dst += 48, data);
    }

The total cost of this approach is 3 data reads, 3 data writes and 25 table reads (from local cache) or 31 128-bit memory bus accesses.
The first approach requires 12 data reads, 9 destination reads and 12 destination writes, which is 33 memory-bus operations in total, and where the writes/read after writes can be more costly.
The second approach has OTOH a cost associated to the tight dependency chain, requiring efficient out-of-order executing architecture to make use of the large latencies (up to 10 cycles) of the memory loads.

Then it's likely that a third option with three passes would be even better:
template <int N>
void pass(uint8_t const *r_or_g_or_b_table, ...) {
   uint8x16x4_t t0,t1,t2,t3; // use 16 registers for R table
   t0 = vld1q_u8_x4(r_or_g_or_b_table);
   t1 = vld1q_u8_x4(r_or_g_or_b_table + 64);
   t2 = vld1q_u8_x4(r_or_g_or_b_table + 128);
   t3 = vld1q_u8_x4(r_or_g_or_b_table + 192);
   auto const k64 = vdupq_n_u8(64);
   auto const k128 = vdupq_n_u8(128);

   while (blocks--) {
      auto d = vld3q_u8(source += 48);
      auto &tmp = d.val[N];
      auto d1 = vsubq_u8(tmp, k64);
      auto d2 = vsubq_u8(tmp, k128);
      auto d3 = vsubq_u8(d1, k64);
      tmp = vtbl4q_u8(t0, tmp);
      tmp = vtbx4q_u8(tmp, t1, d1);
      tmp = vtbx4q_u8(tmp, t2, d2);
      tmp = vtbx4q_u8(tmp, t3, d3);
      vst3q_u8(destination += 48, d);
   }
}

The third approach will first read from src and write to dst converting just the R-channel and copying G,B channels. The second pass will read from dst and write to dst converting just the G-channel, and finally the third pass will process just the B-channel. This will have 9 reads per block and 9 writes per block of 16 pixels  only.
Moreover, with just 24 used registers one can also avoid spilling/restoring the d8..d15 in the function prologue and epilogue.

Very interesting, that's what I was looking for. I'll work on updating the code with your remarks and try the solution of approximating the LUT. Thank you so much.

Surely one can do even better: first pass does vld3, but writes into 3 separate streams. The second pass only reads, transforms and writes G channel and the third pass reads all the channels, transforms B and writes with vst3.

Yes good point, I'll try that as well. Thanks a lot

Ensure you’re compiling with the right optimization flags for your specific processor (-O3 -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4).
Inline Functions: The lookup_neon function is marked inline, but it’s worth checking if the compiler is actually inlining it. You can experiment with __attribute__((always_inline)) or other techniques to ensure inlining happens.

Thank you, I need a deeper answers and solutions to make the code efficient and run faster.

I should preface that my experience has primarily been with higher-level programming and I haven't used Neon. However, I think some of the info can still help a bit.
For starters, in the 'compute_data()' method you have a for loop that runs 256 times. If you update the code inside the for loop so that it contains two static casts running in a single loop. This allows you to run the for loop 128 times instead. This would help reduce the amount of time you would be using up said memory section.
// Function to compute simple example data and lookup tables
void compute_data(const cv::Mat& image, Cache& cache) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        //First loop
        cache.lut_b[i] = static_cast<uchar>(i);
        cache.lut_g[i] = static_cast<uchar>(i);
        cache.lut_r[i] = static_cast<uchar>(i);

        //Second loop
        cache.lut_b[i++] = static_cast<uchar>(i++);
        cache.lut_g[i++] = static_cast<uchar>(i++);
        cache.lut_r[i++] = static_cast<uchar>(i++);
    }
}

This is a minor help and can become a slipper slide to just hard coding the entire loop.
The other area I think you can optimize a bit the code is loading the cache into the registry. When loading the data using vld1q_u8_x4 you also have multiple multiplication operations with '16 * 4 * x'. Where x is some value between 0 and 3. You can create 4 new variables (Or an array) that contain the calculated values for said operations and reference said final values instead of needing to do extra multiplication. The other solution is to create a base variable that just does the 16 * 4 multiplication and then replace the other times said multiplication appears in the rest of the code.
I don't know how you would write it in Neon so my example will be written as if it was a higher level language. You would need to double-check how to write that stuff in Neon.
//First option
uint8x16_t mult0 = 16 * 4 * 0;
uint8x16_t mult1 = 16 * 4 * 1;
uint8x16_t mult2 = 16 * 4 * 2;
uint8x16_t mult3 = 16 * 4 * 3;

//Second option
uint8x16_t mult[4] = new uint8x16_t {16 * 4 * 0, 16 * 4 * 1, 16 * 4 * 2, 16 * 4 * 3}

//Third option
uint8x16_t mult = 16 * 4; 

const uint8x16x4_t vtable_b[4] = {
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_b.data() + mult0),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_b.data() + mult1),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_b.data() + mult2),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_b.data() + mult3)
    };
    const uint8x16x4_t vtable_g[4] = {
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_g.data() + mult0),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_g.data() + mult1),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_g.data() + mult2),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_g.data() + mult3)
    };
    const uint8x16x4_t vtable_r[4] = {
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_r.data() + mult0),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_r.data() + mult1),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_r.data() + mult2),
        vld1q_u8_x4(cache.lut_r.data() + mult3)
    };

I hope my lack of knowledge in Neon didn't hinder too much my explanation of what might help improve your code. After those two things, I haven't seen anything else that would greatly improve your code/for loops.

Unrolling in the source is unlikely to help the compiler generate better asm for the loop.
Compilers like clang can and do already unroll loops for you.  Also, your loop now has six uses i++, with two  in each statement for the "second loop" part.  So in C++17 and later, it assigns to the wrong element.  In earlier C++ versions, there's two unsequenced side-effects. (Is assignment operator a sequence point under C++17? and what would be the result of this expression?).  Not that that matters since that isn't what you wanted your code to do anyway.

Also, creating a lookup table for 16 * 4 * 0..3 is not good.  In the OP's code, they were compile-time constants, with the expression evaluated to a single number at compile time, so the asm will just have a small integer offset baked int.  In your version, uint8x16_t mult[4] = new uint8x16_t {...} isn't even valid C++ (new returns a pointer, but you're assigning to a plain array.  Don't use new there, just an initializer list)  And you didn't declare it static const, so the compiler has to assume something might modify it and actually load from it each time.

Anyway, welcome to Stack Overflow, but it seems you have some things to learn about how C++ compiles to efficient asm.  https://godbolt.org/ is helpful for looking at compiler output for small functions.  (How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?)

Ok. Thanks for the explanation. I've never gone that deep with C++ and compilers so thanks for the extra information. Ill read up on it and see what I can learn. I was clearly off.

Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid” is a good start.
